# How do I populate an email field from a single user “Name” reference?

Tags: entities

I have a content type in which I use an entity reference to reference a Name field in a user account. I am trying to populate an email field in the content type with the email of the entity referenced above. I have tried creating an entity reference view and can get it to show and save: Name, Email Address in the node. However, because of some rules I am using, I really need them to be saved to separate fields. So I tried the Entity Reference Autofill module which seems like it does exactly what I am looking for, but, it only works with existing fields, and for some reason, I can’t get the user account fields to show-up as existing fields when trying to add them to the content type.

So, is there a way for a single reference to populate more fields using the initial reference as a ‘key’?

Or…

Is there a way to get user account fields to show-up as existing fileds so I can just use the Entity Reference Autofill module?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand the need, but once you reference an entity what is the point of adding the values from the referenced entity into the referencing entity?

Is this a UI thing when creating a node? Or a display issue when displaying a node?

If it's a display issue, wouldn't you just create a new display for the reference user for when it is being referenced only showing the fields that you want shown?

To do what I am saying, you would need either https://www.drupal.org/project/ds Display Suite, or embed a view, or call the referenced user fields in a template or module.